Can a GitLab CI_JOB_TOKEN be used to clone repositories during a GitLab CI pipeline?
During the CI pipeline of Project A, I am trying to clone another repository on our GitLab instance (self-hosted) by using the CI_JOB_TOKEN. I already use it successfully for accessing Git submodules etc.
But when trying to git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:$CI_JOB_TOKEN@my.gitlab.instance.com/group/project-that-throws-error.git, I get the following error:
Cloning into 'project-that-throws-error'...
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2FA enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password. See https://my.gitlab.instance.com/help/topics/git/troubleshooting_git#error-on-git-fetch-http-basic-access-denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://my.gitlab.instance.com/group/project-that-throws-error.git'

I also set the Basic Authentication in the gitlab-ci.yml file like so:
$token = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("gitlab-ci-token:$CI_JOB_TOKEN"))
git config http.https://my.gitlab.instance.com/group/project-that-throws-error.extraheader "Authorization: Basic $token"

In the Web UI, for Project that throws error, I allowed my Project A CI token access by entering it into Settings -> CI/CD -> Token Access -> Allow CI job tokens from the following projects to access this project.
Is it possible to use the GitLab CI Token in this way? How can I make authentication work?
I cannot use SSH as an alternative authentication method.

There are 3 access tokens for accessing another repository, and all works in the pipelines:

Personal Tokens
Project Access Tokens
$CI_JOB_TOKEN

Unless you are doing something else, you don't need extraheader. Also there is a known issue with one version of curl (8.2) that causes this.

Thank you for the hint. I got it working by using a Project Access token with read_repository rights.
The extraheader is needed because of Kerberos on our GitLab instance.
I used another call git -c extraheder.http="Authentication Basic xyz" clone ... as described in this question
